# How to export a finished application from Qt?

Tags: qt, user-interface, export

I have a simple basic application with some gui stuff and i want to brag to my friend with it. How can i package up a .exe or something to send to him. I have looked all over the internet and cant find exactly what im looking for. Can someone please tell me how to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This process is called [deployment](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/deployment.html). Perhaps you just missed correct search keyword?